# Stability of a closed loop control system

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I have a question regarding control theory. Say I have a closed loop feedback system and I have found the closed loop transfer function, how would I then assess the stability of my closed loop system ? I have heard about the terms "poles and zeros". How would one find these and use them to comment on the stability ? Could I use software such as matlab for this analysis?

Comment: Write out the closed loop transfer function as ratio of two polynomials. Zeros are roots of the numerator polynomial. Poles  are roots of denominator. Stable if *all* the poles are in left half of complex plane, i.e. their real component is <0.

Comment: @PeteW, bingo! I haven't heard of that explanation, it is very good! -NN

Answer (score 1):

A transfer function of a closed-loop feedback control system is written in the form:

$$ T(s) = \frac{H(s)}{G(s)} $$

where $G(s)$ is called the characteristic polynomial of the system. The poles and zeros of the system are defined:

- Zeros $\rightarrow$ Roots of $H(s)$
- Poles $\rightarrow$ Roots of $G(s)$

The stability of the closed-loop system can be determined by looking at the roots of the characteristic polynomial. Consider the general case at which the poles are complex numbers of the form $p = \sigma + j\omega$ (if $\omega = 0 \rightarrow$ poles are real numbers). Now, there will always be one of these three following cases:

- If at least one pole has positive real part (i.e. $\sigma > 0$) then the closed-loop system is **unstable**.
- If all the poles have negative real part (i.e. $\sigma <0$) then the closed-loop system is **strictly stable**.
- If all the poles have negative real parts and at least one has real part equal to $0$ (i.e. $\sigma = 0$) then the closed-loop system may be **marginally stable** or **unstable**. Generally, in this case you need to further investigate the stability of the system.

Finally, of course you can use software like MATLAB to determine the stability of an open-loop or closed-loop system. Let's consider the system:

$$ G(s) = \frac{10}{s^2+3s+2} $$

By using the following piece of code you can find the poles, zeros and check the stability of the system:

```
s = tf('s');
G = 10/(s^2+3*s+2);
zero(G)
pole(G)
isstable(G)
```

You can check the MATLAB official documentation for more information on these functions.

Comment: the poles tell us about the stability of the system so what do the zeros tell us about the system?